# Ruby-on-rails Twitter Bootstrap field with error styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Im using Ruby on Rails 4 with twitter bootstrap to display a `form_for` (twitter bs `form_horizontal`). The styling below works correctly (label, input and hint display next to each other ) for normal fields (non error'd) when rails wraps elements in the `field_with_errors` div however the hint is dropped to the beneath the input element.

```
<div class="control-group required">
        <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="control-label" for="lot_commonname_id">Common Name</label></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="field_with_errors"><select id="lot_commonname_id" name="lot[commonname_id]"><option value="">Please select</option>
               <option value="1">x</option>
               <option value="2">y</option>
               <option value="3">z</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="hint">
               <a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="xyz test.">
               <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
               </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}

.form-horizontal .field_with_errors
{
 margin: 0;
}

.form-horizontal .field_with_errors:before, .form-horizontal .field_with_errors::after 
{
 display: block;
 clear: none;
}
```

the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a78B5/6/ demos the problem

Answer (score 0):

Divs default to display:block so it will naturally drop down to be below your input.  Add styling to use display:inline or display:inline-block and it will move back to being next to your text box.

Comment: .hint {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
} makes no difference.

Comment: @user2732663 The field_with_errors style is also block, not inline-block which means it takes up the whole width of the container and will push the next div (your hint in this case) down.